# gmail api php updatevacation

Tags: php, google-api, gmail-api, google-api-php-client, settings

I use the following code to retrieve the vacation settings. It uses the Google API PHP client library and the Gmail API to gain access to the gmail platform

I cannot work out how to set a vacation. Does anyone have some sample code that does this?

```
    public function getVacation($userToken)
    {
        // Get the API client and construct the service object.
        $client = $this->getClient($userToken);
        $service = new Google_Service_Gmail($client);

        // get the vacation settings
        $user = 'me';
        $results = $service->users_settings->getVacation($user);
        print_r($results);
    }


function getClient($userToken)
{
   ... a method that does the connection. for some reason stackoverflow sees it as too much code, but it works :) and i get vacation info.
}
```

Comment: this is the code i am using.

Comment: `public function setVacation($userToken)
 {
  // Get the API client and construct the service object.
  $client = $this->getClient($userToken);
  $service = new Google_Service_Gmail($client);
  
  // get the vacation settings
  $user = 'me';
  $results = $service->users_settings->getVacation($user);
  print_r($results);
  
  // change the subject
  $results->responseSubject = 'Out of Office.';
  
  $results2 = $service->users_settings->updateVacation($user,$vacation);
  print_r($results2);
 }`

Comment: getting error
 Argument 2 passed to Google_Service_Gmail_Resource_UsersSettings::updateVacation() must be an instance of Google_Service_Gmail_VacationSettings, null given

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should look into using [Update vacation](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/settings/updateVacation)

```
$results = $service->users_settings->getVacation("me");
$results->responseSubject = 'Out of Office.';
$results = $service->users_settings->updateVacation("me", $results);
```

Comment: Thanks you are a star. For anyone else using this car $user needs to= "me"